# Incorrect Number of Dimensions Error When Fitting a KNN Model

Tags: r, classification, knn, model-fitting

I am trying to fit a KNN classification model into the folds I created but I keep getting the same error:

"Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: Error in apply(weightClass, 1, order, decreasing = TRUE)[1, ]: incorrect number of dimensions"

I don't know what's wrong. This si the code that I have been using:

`

```
folds <- vfold_cv(data = weighted_cps_train, v = 5)

#Creating a recipe object:

weighted_cps_rec <- 
  recipe(formula = offpov ~ ., data = weighted_cps_train) %>%
  step_dummy(immigrant, 
             pubhous, 
             foodstmp, 
             sex, 
             vetstat, 
             labforce, 
             diffany, 
             himcaidly, 
             himcarely, 
             phinsur, 
             anycovnw, 
             kidcneed, 
             workly)
  step_center(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_nzv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_other() %>%

# The COVID group included an additional step (downsample), but I'm not sure it would suit us.
# This is their code:

  themis::step_downsample(employed) %>% # subsampling due to class imbalances between employment class
  step_other()

# Creating a KNN model with hyper parameter tuning:

# Creating a KNN model specification:

weighted_cps_knn_mod <-
  nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>%
  set_engine(engine = "kknn") %>%
  set_mode(mode = "classification")

# Creating a workflow:

weighted_cps_knn_workflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(spec = weighted_cps_knn_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe = weighted_cps_rec)

# Creating a tuning grid:

weighted_cps_knn_grid <- grid_regular(neighbors(range = c(1, 15)), levels = 2)

# Estimating models with re-sampling for each row in the tuning grid:

weighted_cps_knn_res <- weighted_cps_knn_workflow %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = folds,
            grid = weighted_cps_knn_grid,
            control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE),
            metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
```

`

I tried to change the settings in the specifications of the model but nothing worked.

This is a snapshot of the data I'm using. It's from IPUMS CPS.

`

```
> dput(head(weighted_cps_train[]))
structure(list(statefip = c(12, 12, 53, 39, 4, 29), county = c(12086, 
12109, NA, NA, 4013, NA)), row.names = c(269330L, 87519L, 332249L, 
207945L, 322416L, 230928L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(iris[]))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(weighted_cps_train[, c(1, 3)]))
structure(list(statefip = c(12, 12, 53, 39, 4, 29), county = c(12086, 
12109, NA, NA, 4013, NA)), row.names = c(269330L, 87519L, 332249L, 
207945L, 322416L, 230928L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(weighted_cps_train[]))
structure(list(statefip = c(12, 12, 53, 39, 4, 29), metro = c(3, 
3, 3, 1, 2, 3), county = c(12086, 12109, NA, NA, 4013, NA), ownershp = c(22, 
10, 10, 10, 22, 10), hhincome = c(114000, 79433, 98417, 131840, 
15000, 17301), pubhous = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), foodstmp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), stampmo = structure(c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), labels = structure(0:12, names = c("NIU", 
"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 
"Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve")), label = "Number of months received food stamps", var_desc = "STAMPMO specifies the number of months the household received Food Stamps during the previous calendar year. For information about the Food Stamp program, see (FOODSTMP).", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), stampval = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), asecwt = c(1665.09, 3296.28, 1719.06, 
3452.21, 1793.53, 3496.75), age = structure(c(41L, 15L, 63L, 
45L, 3L, 10L), labels = c(`Under 1 year` = 0L, `90 (90+, 1988-2002)` = 90L, 
`99+` = 99L), label = "Age", var_desc = "Age gives each person's age at last birthday.", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), race = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100), marst = c(4, 6, 1, 4, 6, 6), vetstat = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    famsize = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L), labels = structure(0:29, names = c("Missing", 
    "1 family member present", "2 family members present", "3 family members present", 
    "4 family members present", "5 family members present", "6 family members present", 
    "7 family members present", "8 family members present", "9 family members present", 
    "10 family members present", "11 family members present", 
    "12 family members present", "13 family members present", 
    "14 family members present", "15 family members present", 
    "16 family members present", "17 family members present", 
    "18 family members present", "19 family members present", 
    "20 family members present", "21 family members present", 
    "22 family members present", "23 family members present", 
    "24 family members present", "25 family members present", 
    "26 family members present", "27 family members present", 
    "28 family members present", "29 family members present")), label = "Number of own family members in hh", var_desc = "FAMSIZE counts the number of own family members residing with each individual, including the person her/himself. Persons not living with others related to them by blood, marriage, or adoption are coded 1.\n\nNote that FAMSIZE is an IPUMS-derived variable using IPUMS-derived family interrelationships, which will not necessarily correspond to the Census Bureau's family definitions. See FTYPE, FAMKIND, and FAMREL for variables that correspond to Census family units. IPUMS does not currently offer a corresponding variable for the size of the Census family unit, but variables necessitating this information such as POVERTY already take the Census family unit size into account.\n\nAn Introduction to the Family Interrelationship Variables can be found on IPUMS-USA. On this page you'll find information on how IPUMS family interrelationship variables are constructed, common uses of these variables, and specific examples of how these variables can be used efficiently.", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "integer")), nchild = structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), labels = c(`0 children present` = 0L, `1 child present` = 1L, 
    `9+` = 9L), label = "Number of own children in household", var_desc = "NCHILD counts the number of own children (of any age or marital status) residing with each individual. NCHILD includes step-children and adopted children as well as biological children. Persons with no children present are coded 0.\n\nNote that NCHILD is an IPUMS-derived variable using IPUMS-derived family interrelationships. Thus NCHILD may differ from any family information that comes from just the Census family definitions. See for example FTYPE, FAMKIND, and FAMREL for more on Census family units.", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "integer")), nchlt5 = structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), labels = c(`No children under age 5` = 0L, `1 child under age 5` = 1L, 
    `9+` = 9L), label = "Number of own children under age 5 in hh", var_desc = "NCHLT5 counts the number of own children age 4 and under residing with each individual. NCHLT5 includes step-children and adopted children as well as biological children. Persons with no children under 5 present are coded 0.\n\nNote that NCHLT5 is an IPUMS-derived variable using IPUMS-derived family interrelationships. Thus NCHLT5 may differ from any family information that comes from just the Census family definitions. See for example FTYPE, FAMKIND, and FAMREL for more on Census family units.", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "integer")), bpl = c(30005, 9900, 9900, 9900, 
    20000, 9900), yrimmig = c(1995, NA, NA, NA, 2019, NA), citizen = c(4, 
    1, 1, 1, 5, 1), hispan = c(612, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0), empstat = c(10, 
    34, 36, 10, NA, NA), labforce = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), occ = c(4300, 
    0, 0, 430, 0, 0), ind = c(8590, 0, 0, 3570, 0, 0), classwkr = c(28, 
    NA, NA, 21, NA, NA), uhrsworkt = c(40, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA
    ), educ = c(111, 40, 111, 81, NA, NA), diffany = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    occly = c(4300, 0, 0, 430, 0, 0), indly = c(8590, 0, 0, 3570, 
    0, 0), classwly = c(28, NA, NA, 22, NA, NA), workly = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    incfarm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA), incss = c(0, 0, 2400, 0, 
    NA, NA), incint = c(0, 10, 21, 250, NA, NA), offpov = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    poverty = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 10, 10), migrate1 = c(1, 1, 1, 
    4, 1, 1), himcaidly = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), himcarely = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    phinsur = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), moop = c(100, 11840, 50425, 8750, 
    150, 12110), anycovnw = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), kidcneed = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    union = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), immigrant = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
    ), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(269330L, 
87519L, 332249L, 207945L, 322416L, 230928L), class = "data.frame")
```

`

Comment: To answer this question, we might need some example data to make this reproducible.

Comment: Please share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) like `dput` so we can copy/paste it into R for testing rather than having to re-type everything.